# ifort's real-size flag equivalent for C

Tags: c, fortran, intel-fortran, compiler-flags

Do `gcc` and `cl` have an equivalent for `ifort` [real-size](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-7E67A24F-6C9E-4EC0-8270-B052F9B15D28.htm) compiler flag? If not, what should I use instead? MACRO?

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION
  #define REAL double
#else
  #define REAL float
#endif
REAL myvar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no "universal float" whose size can be controlled with a compiler switch. We use an approach similar to yours, albeit with a `typedef` instead of a `define`:

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION
    typedef double real;
#else
    typedef float real;
#endif
```

There's a bit more to it than just the floating-point type, however. For example, consider these function signatures:

```
double exp(double x);
float expf(float x);
long double expl(long double x);
```

Each function has a suffix denoting the type of arguments and return values. Or consider the types of floating-point literals:

```
1.2f   // float
1.2    // double
```

If you want to be on the safe side, you'd have to write macros for these cases, too:

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION
    #define REAL(x) x
    #define SIN(x) sin(x)
#else
    #define REAL(x) x ## f
    #define SIN(x) sinf(x)
#endif
```

In practice, I've found that with optimisation switched on (`-O2` or more), the compiler works out the best function signatures and which type to use for literals, so I just use unadorned functions and literals in order not to clutter the code. This seems to work for gcc and for the Intel and PGI compilers.

Answer (score 1):

gfortran has compile-time option `-fdefault-real-8`.   But not gcc.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it is not so clear from the question, but I want to compile C code, not Fortran code.